# bootstrap-datetimepicker for bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I want to use [bootstrap-datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) with bootstrap 4 but I have some problems.

For this purpose I changed something like:

1. `pull-right` to `float-right`
2. `table-condensed` to `table-sm`
3. `glyphicons` to `fontawesome`

but it did not work :(

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/testone/9hcjuf2z/1/)

Can anyone help me for converting this project to new bootstrap version?

Comment: [eonasdan-datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) does not support bootstrap v.4, the new version of the library is called [tempus dominus](https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We've made a fork with the fixes with detail documentation:

#### Forked Repository:

- [**TechnoVista Limited/Bootstrap 4 DateTimePicker**](https://github.com/technovistalimited/bootstrap4-datetimepicker) - Github

#### Usage:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if (window.jQuery().datetimepicker) {
        $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
            // Formats
            // follow MomentJS docs: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/
            format: 'DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm A',

            // Your Icons
            // as Bootstrap 4 is not using Glyphicons anymore
            icons: {
                time: 'fa fa-clock-o',
                date: 'fa fa-calendar',
                up: 'fa fa-chevron-up',
                down: 'fa fa-chevron-down',
                previous: 'fa fa-chevron-left',
                next: 'fa fa-chevron-right',
                today: 'fa fa-check',
                clear: 'fa fa-trash',
                close: 'fa fa-times'
            }
        });
    }
});
```

#### Credits:

Thanks to [`Eonasdan`](https://github.com/Eonasdan) for the awesome library. Thanks to 非良 (`wgbbiao`) for their fork too. Thanks to [Camille Anelli's blog](https://www.camilleanelli.fr/datetimepicker-bootstrap4/) for the reminder about the icons.

Comment: Great Thx alot working smooth with Bootstrap v4.4.1

Answer (score 12):

It's ok for me with Bootstrap4, what is your problem ? (sorry for my bad english :')

```
Edit lines with ".in"collapse to ".show" and icons
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fayange/05ug7khd/3/)

Answer (score 5):

@Stéphanie your demo more than made up for the short English explanation. Thanks!

For anyone else that might need to solve this, here go a very specific directions: (All based on @Stéphanie's answer below - checkout her demo.)
There are four strings you need to search in the code:

> "collapse in":" 
>   g=f.find(".in") 
>   .collapse:not(.in) 
>   (g.removeClass("in"),h.addClass("in")

and in each case replace    **in**   with;   **show**   so that it will look like the following. Save the file and the calendar should work. Good luck!

> "collapse show":" 
>   g=f.find(".show") 
>   .collapse:not(.show) 
>   (g.removeClass("show"),h.addClass("show")